# Reduce query redundancy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    invoiceNo AS Bill_No,
    SUM(ISNULL((OFI.[New Quantity] * OFI.[Unit Sell Price]),0)) AS Amount,
    SUM(ISNULL(((OFI.[New Quantity] * OFI.[Unit Sell Price]) + FBP.[Packing/Delivery Charges] + FBP.[Miscellaneous Charge]) * (FBP.[Additional Discount Percent] / 100), 0)) AS Discount 
FROM
    dbo.[Final Payment Bill] FBP
JOIN
    dbo.[Order] o ON o.finalPaymentBill_invoiceNo = FBP.invoiceNo
JOIN
    dbo.[Ordered Food Item] OFI ON o.[Order Number] = OFI.Order_orderNo
GROUP BY
    FBP.invoiceNo
```

As seen on the query, I had to write the same sum function twice for calculation. Is there any other way so that i don't have to write it again?

PS: I am unsure of correct way to put this question.

Comment: You can use CTE and do the calculation that is repeated within the CTE codes

Comment: You could write it as a function however the SQL compiler will probably optimise this for you so there is no performance loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use subquery for this

```
select 
   invoiceNo as Bill_No,
   sum(FinalPrice) as Amount,
   sum(ISNULL((FinalPrice + FBP.[Packing/Delivery Charges] + FBP.[Miscellaneous Charge]) * (FBP.[Additional Discount Percent] / 100) ,0)) as Discount 
from dbo.[Final Payment Bill] FBP
join dbo.[Order] o
    on o.finalPaymentBill_invoiceNo = FBP.invoiceNo
join (select Order_orderNo, (OFI.[New Quantity] * OFI.[Unit Sell Price]) FinalPrice from dbo.[Ordered Food Item]) OFI
    on o.[Order Number] = OFI.Order_orderNo
group by FBP.invoiceNo
```

and CTE for better readability

```
with OFI as
(
   select Order_orderNo, (OFI.[New Quantity] * OFI.[Unit Sell Price]) FinalPrice 
   from dbo.[Ordered Food Item]
)
select 
   invoiceNo as Bill_No,
   sum(FinalPrice) as Amount,
   sum(ISNULL((FinalPrice + FBP.[Packing/Delivery Charges] + FBP.[Miscellaneous Charge]) * (FBP.[Additional Discount Percent] / 100) ,0)) as Discount 
from dbo.[Final Payment Bill] FBP
join dbo.[Order] o
    on o.finalPaymentBill_invoiceNo = FBP.invoiceNo
join OFI
    on o.[Order Number] = OFI.Order_orderNo
group by FBP.invoiceNo
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplication is no-biggie.  But, you can simplify your code.  `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values, so this probably does what you want:

```
select invoiceNo as Bill_No,
       sum(OFI.[New Quantity] * OFI.[Unit Sell Price]) as Amount,
       sum(OFI.[New Quantity] * OFI.[Unit Sell Price]) + FBP.[Packing/Delivery Charges] + FBP.[Miscellaneous Charge]) * (FBP.[Additional Discount Percent] / 100) as Discount 
from dbo.[Final Payment Bill] FBP join
     dbo.[Order] o
     on o.finalPaymentBill_invoiceNo = FBP.invoiceNo join
     dbo.[Ordered Food Item] OFI
     on o.[Order Number] = OFI.Order_orderNo
group by FBP.invoiceNo;
```

You *can* avoid the duplication using a CTE or subquery (or in other cases, `apply`).  But that hardly seems worth the effort in this case.

A more significant issue is that `+` does not ignore `NULL` values, so if any of the `FPB` columns are `NULL`, then all the values for that row are ignored.

Comment: You have removed the `FBP.[Packing/Delivery Charges] + FBP.[Miscellaneous Charge]) * (FBP.[Additional Discount Percent] / 100` part from the `ISNULL` as well from the `SUM`

Answer (score 0):

The duplication you have there is not a problem. But you could remove it if you created a calculated column on the `[Ordered Food Item]` table

```
ALTER TABLE [Ordered Food Item] 
ADD Amount 
AS ([New Quantity] * [Unit Sell Price])
```